# If $a$ is a primitive root modulo $p$, then $(p-1) | ord(a)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p^e\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory

I'm a bit confused on a fact that my book has been using rather liberally without proof and I'm sure I'm missing something incredibly simple. Plainly stated, my question is if $a$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ so that
$$a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$$
Then why is it that if the order of $a$ modulo $p^e, e > 1$ is $m$, then $p-1|m$? I don't understand this since I don't see any connection between the order of some element in $p$ versus it's order in $p^2, p^3, ....., p^e$ (this is also the "heart" of my question, what is the connection of orders of elements modulo $p, p^2, p^3, ...., p^e$?).

Furthermore, $\phi(p^e) = p^{e-1}(p-1)$ but I don't see why this necessarily shows that $$(p-1)\ |\ \text{ord}_{\mathbb{Z}/p^e\mathbb{Z}}(a)$$

Could someone please enlighten me on this?

Comment: I think you don't mean $p-1|m$, but rather $m|p-1$. Note that $m$ is always smaller or equal to $p-1$. Same for the second expression

Comment: @vrugtehagel : he does mean $p-1 \mid m$. The reason is the following : let $m=ord(a)$. Then $a^m = 1$ (mod $p^e$). But this means that $p^e \mid a^m -1 $, which in turn implies (but is not equivalent to) $p\mid a^m -1$, so that $a^m = 1$ (mod $p$). So by the well known properties of $ord$, $ord(a)|m$, $p-1\mid m$ (the only detail left is to show that $a$ is invertible mod $p^e$, but I think you know how to prove this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually follows from a more general result.

**Proposition**: Let $G$ and $H$ be groups and $\varphi: G \to H$ be a homomorphism.  Then $\DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{ord} \ord(\varphi(g)) \mid \ord(g)$ for all $g \in G$.

*Proof*: Letting $m = \ord(g)$, then $\varphi(g)^m = \varphi(g^m) = \varphi(1) = 1$.  Then $\ord(\varphi(g)) \mid m$.

Now apply the proposition to your primitive root mod $p$ and the quotient map
$$
\pi: \mathbb{Z}/p^e \mathbb{Z} \to \frac{\mathbb{Z}/p^e \mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}/p^e \mathbb{Z}} \cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \, .
$$

Answer (score 2):

Max basically answered this question so just to reiterate what he posted in the comments, if $a$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ then let $m$ denote the order of $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p^e\mathbb{Z}$, then we have
$$a^m \equiv 1 \pmod {p^e} \implies p^e | a^m - 1 \implies p | a^m - 1 \implies a^m \equiv 1 \pmod p$$
But then $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ since it is a primitive root modulo $p$, then $ord(a)_{\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}} | m$ so indeed $p-1 | m$